# Set image size on media and text block with a function

Tags: functions, images, block-editor

I'm using the Media & Text block within Gutenberg. You can adjust the size of the image by dragging the small blue circle:

[image: WordPress Media & Text Block]

Looking at the Media & Text settings on the right, it doesn't look possible to select the image size.

When using the stand alone image block, you can adjust the image size, like so:

[image: Media Size]

Is it possible to set an image size using a function for this block type? I need the design to be consistent on the front-end.

Comment: Can't you define a new image size and use that in the first dropdown?

Comment: The **Image Size** dropdown in the screengrab is for other media. It doesn't look like it's possible to set an image size within Media & Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image size dropdown was added in [PR #24795](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/24795) which was included in Gutenberg v9.1 and then included in [WordPress 5.6](https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-5-6/#image-size-control-added-to-the-media--text-block).